# My computer freezes after log in!

Tags: 14.04

I have a lenovo desktop with a amd athlon 64 x2, 2 gb ram, a ide had drive and nvidea goforce 6100 graphics. i installed the 14.04 32 bit version and it got to the log in screen where it performed just like a regular computer but when i log in, afer a second or too, it becomes completely unresponsive. i also downloaded the other 2 variations, 64 bit and 66 bit amd mac, but they all do the same thing, i dont know what to do

Answer (score 0):

OK... Your computer runs over 32b or 64b ? Do you know?

I have no idea of what it can be but MAYBE some file was corrupted during/after installation.

Check this points:

- Are you using the right bit version of Ubuntu? 32/64
- During install time, any errors or windows poped up?

If you answer *YES* to the first question and *NO* to the second one, try accessing the recovery mode during boot and run the *dpkg*. It will check for corrupted system files and maybe solve the problem.

Comment: i think its a 64 bit, but i tried all three editions, 14.04 32 bit, 14.04 64 bit, and 14.04 64 bit (mac) AMD, i have no clue why non of the versions would work, amd and nvidea are supported, right
?

Comment: i went into recovery and ran DPKG when i exited, it went to the desktop but it was super slow, so i restarted, it did the original problem, so every time i wanna use it, i have to go into recovery mode, it gave me a warning that when going to the desktop from recovery mode, some thing baout graphic so it might be graphics issue

Comment: Do you hava Windows installed too? If so, you can go to System Preferences (or something like that) and check your version of Windows. It will be the same for Ubuntu.

Comment: I do think they are both supported but check the foruns to find out if anyone else had a similar problem.

Instead of logging in through graphic mode, try to use one of the main terminals.
    1. Pres ctrl shift F1 and log in.
    2. Do a full update and upgrade on the system. Just copy&paste if you understand the code - 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade'

Let it run to the end, 'sudo reboot' and they try logging in.

@yoyo13579